# Search for keyword in user input and find the corresponding keyword in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, user-input

I am doing a search engine, I tried to code so that when the user input some of the keywords, it will search the keyword in the dictionary and print of the key and items.

```
Canada = {'name': 'Canada', 'continent': 'North America', 'capital': 'Ottawa', 'currency': 'Canadian dollar',
          'population': '32,268,240', 'area': '9,970,610'}
Laos = {'name': 'Laos', 'continent': 'Asia', 'capital': 'Vientiane', 'currency': 'Lao kip',
          'population': '5,924,145', 'area': '236,800'}
Mexico = {'name': 'Mexico', 'continent': 'North America', 'capital': 'Mexico City', 'currency': 'Mexico peso',
        'population': '107,029,400', 'area': '1,958,201'}
key_words = ("Canada", "Mexico", "Laos")
key = ("area", "population", "currency")
user_input = input("Type: ")

for word in user_input.split():
   if word in key_words:
      print()
```

Could you guy help me with the coding so that:
For example:
When the user input: "currency of Mexico" it will print out: Mexico peso, or when user input: "area of Laos", it will print out 236,800.

Comment: And why did you think the posted code might achieve that?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't post the question properly, I have edited it now.

Comment: first `split()` text into words, next check every word in every dictionary. Most word may have to compare with keys - ie. `area` - but some with values - ie. `Mexico`. Or keep all dictionares in one dictinary and use name as key - `data= {"Mexico": {'area': '1,958,201'}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set some rules for the user to follow, you could build a fuzzy query search engine from scratch but thats not something thats going to happen today. For now make it so the user specifies what they want eg. `ITEM COUNTRY`.

```sh
Enter <query> <country>: currency mexico
>> Mexico pesos
```

You could restructure your code like so using one dictionary to hold all your data instead of breaking it up into variables.

```
database = {
    'canada': {
        'name': 'Canada',
        'continent': 'North America',
        'capital': 'Ottawa',
        'currency': 'Canadian dollar',
        'population': '32,268,240',
        'area': '9,970,610'
        },
    'laos' : {
        'name': 'Laos',
        'continent': 'Asia',
        'capital': 'Vientiane',
        'currency': 'Lao kip',
          'population': '5,924,145',
        'area': '236,800'
        },
    'mexico': {
        'name': 'Mexico',
        'continent': 'North America',
        'capital': 'Mexico City',
        'currency': 'Mexico peso',
        'population': '107,029,400',
        'area': '1,958,201'
        }
    }

user_input = input("Enter your query: ")
user_input = user_input.lower().split(' ')

# find country
country = None
for keyword in user_input:
    if keyword in database:
        # using .pop() removes the country from the list
        country = user_input.pop(user_input.index(keyword))

# If the user entered a valid country
if country:
    for keyword in user_input:
        if keyword in database.get(country):
            print(keyword, database[country][keyword])

else:
    print('Could not find that country in the database')
```

EDIT: Updated code so you can be more ambiguous and type keywords/country in any order and have multiple keywords

example:

```
Enter query: population and currency of mexico
>> currency Mexico peso
>> population 107,029,400
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really helped me a lot. But I just wonder, what if the user input keywords along with other words. Is there any way to improve the code so it could fit? Thank you in advance

Comment: @Pentagone I've updated the code so now you can enter keywords in any order and enter multiple keywords to find, eg. `mexico capital currency` or even `population mexico area`. If you want to get create a search engine like google where you can type `what is the population of mexico and its area?` then you will need to look into fuzzy string matching (google it)

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
Canada = {'name': 'Canada', 'continent': 'North America', 'capital': 'Ottawa', 'currency': 'Canadian dollar',
          'population': '32,268,240', 'area': '9,970,610'}
Laos = {'name': 'Laos', 'continent': 'Asia', 'capital': 'Vientiane', 'currency': 'Lao kip',
          'population': '5,924,145', 'area': '236,800'}
Mexico = {'name': 'Mexico', 'continent': 'North America', 'capital': 'Mexico City', 'currency': 'Mexico peso',
        'population': '107,029,400', 'area': '1,958,201'}

countries = {'Canada' : Canada, 'Mexico' :Mexico, 'Laos' : Laos} 

user_input = input("Type: ")

asked_country = list(set(user_input.split()).intersection(countries.keys()))[0] 
output = list(set(countries[asked_country].keys()))[0]
print(countries[asked_country][output]) 

# Type: currency of Mexico             
# Mexico peso
```

Answer (score 0):

Not short, but more clear and wider solution. For example for query like `Area and population of Canada`, it will print:

```
Type: area and population of Canada
results:
area = 9,970,610
population = 32,268,240
```

```
from collections import defaultdict

Canada = {'name': 'Canada', 'continent': 'North America', 'capital': 'Ottawa', 'currency': 'Canadian dollar',
          'population': '32,268,240', 'area': '9,970,610'}
Laos = {'name': 'Laos', 'continent': 'Asia', 'capital': 'Vientiane', 'currency': 'Lao kip',
          'population': '5,924,145', 'area': '236,800'}
Mexico = {'name': 'Mexico', 'continent': 'North America', 'capital': 'Mexico City', 'currency': 'Mexico peso',
        'population': '107,029,400', 'area': '1,958,201'}

key = set(["area", "population", "currency"])

# build the forward and reverse indexes
forward_index = [Canada, Laos, Mexico]
reverse_index = defaultdict(set)

for i, description in enumerate(forward_index):
    phrase = ' '.join(['%s %s'%(k,v) for k, v in description.items()])
    words = phrase.lower().split()
    for w in words:
        reverse_index[w].add(i)

# search
user_input = input("Type: ")

res = None
keywords = set()
for word in user_input.lower().split():
    if word in key:
        keywords.add(word)

    posting_set = reverse_index.get(word, None)

    # tolerant search: skip missing words
    if posting_set is None:
        continue

    if res is None:
        res = posting_set
    else:
        res = res.intersection(posting_set)

# print all the results
if res is None or len(keywords) == 0:
    print("<nothing found>")
else:
    print("results:")
    for idx in res:
        desc = forward_index[idx]
        for kw in keywords:
            print("%s = %s" % (kw, desc[kw]))
```